# wordpress own plugin has_shortcode does not work

Tags: wordpress

I am using WP 4.3 and I created a plugin which is used only from one single page where I have the shortcode `[my_sc]`.

I tried do realize like this:

```
add_action('init', 'my_enqu_script');
function my_enqu_script(){
    global $post;
    $content = $post->post_content;

    if(has_shortcode($content, 'my_sc')){
        wp_register_script(......);
        wp_localize_script(......);
        wp_enqueue_script('jQuery');
        wp_enqueue_script('my_script');
    }

    function my_func(){
        //do something
    }
    add_shortcode('my_sc', 'my_func');
}
```

Unfortunatly, that (has_shortcode) does not work. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be wrapping the `add_shortcode()` bit in the `my_enqu_script()` function. Instead, add the shortcode, and then hook the other function into an appropriate hook:

```
function my_func(){
    //do something
}
add_shortcode('my_sc', 'my_func');

function my_enqu_script(){
    global $post;
    $content = $post->post_content;

    if ( has_shortcode($content, 'my_sc') ) {
        wp_register_script(......);
        wp_localize_script(......);
        wp_enqueue_script('jQuery');
        wp_enqueue_script('my_script');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqu_script');
```

You should also consider using the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) action hook, instead of `init`, since `init` is too early for `global $post;` to be in scope.

Comment: Thanks rnevius. I get following message now: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in....  on the line $content = $post->post_content;

Comment: As mentioned, `init` is the wrong action hook to be using (because the WP object hasn't been set up yet). At the earliest, you should be using `wp`. However, I recommend changing `init` to `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create your function and call the function [`add_shortcode()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode).

e.g.

```
function my_function(){
    echo 'Test';
}
add_shortcode('my_sc', 'my_function');
```

Also you used `:` instead of `;` which might have been causing the failure.

You should add this to your `functions.php` file or create a seperate file (best practice) and `include()` it.

Comment: The shortcode function name doesn't not have to be the same as the shortcode name.

Comment: I just corrected the ":" to ";". It was a copy-paste mistake - sorry. But it does not helps me. :-(

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do then?
Does the shortcode not work? Or are you referring to the code above that?